# MVVM Dependency Property and DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

I'm having issues figuring out something that's probably pretty stupid.

I have this xaml on a parent control for my user control:

```
<Map:LocationInformationControl FarmerID="{Binding SelectedFarmerID}"></Map:LocationInformationControl>
```

In the control that this xaml is on has the SelectedFarmerID property on it's viewmodel and all is fine there.

My LocationInformationControl is a custom control that I have this dependency property on:

```
       public static readonly DependencyProperty FarmerIDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "FarmerID", 
        typeof(int),
        typeof(LocationInformationControl), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFarmerIDChanged)
            ));

    public int FarmerID
    {
        get 
        { 
            return (int)GetValue(FarmerIDProperty); 
        }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(FarmerIDProperty, value); 
        }
    }
```

This is my On Property Changed Callback

```
    private static void OnFarmerIDChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

It fires fine, and everything is great.  But when I hook up the view model to the custom control like this:

```
this.DataContext = new LocationInformationViewModel()
```

The property changed callback won't fire anymore.  I'm assuming it's because I'm changing the data context of the control so it won't find FarmerID anymore.  But is there anyway I can have a ViewModel set up like that and still have a dependency property on the same control?

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: Not sure why, but your design appears to be incorrect.  Your control is good, but you shouldn't create a ViewModel for your control.  Control logic is, by nature, UI logic, and it is fine to use codebehind to run the UI.  You should be allowing users to bind DPs on your control to properties of their VM, not a VM you are forcing them to use.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right.  I just won't use a view model for my UserControl.

Comment: I made the same mistake when I was starting up with MVVM.  It becomes more obvious when you are trying to use it.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, this gives me now way to update the view with data from the code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common mistake to set the `DataContext` of a `UserControl` to itself, or a view model as in your case, *from inside that control*. There are many beginner tutorials that show this, but that is simply because it is one of the quickest and easiest ways to get data into the UI in WPF. [Of course, there *are* exceptions.]

So instead of setting the `DataContext` to the view model internally and `Binding` to your `UserControl` properties from inside the control like this...:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FarmerID}" />
```

... dont' set the `DataContext` and use the following `RelativeSource Binding`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FarmerID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type
YourLocalXmlNamespacePrefix:LocationInformationControl}}}" />
```

In this way, the `Binding` will look for the `FarmerID` in the `LocationInformationControl` control, no matter whether the `DataContext` is set or not. You can *almost* think of this as setting the `DataContext`, but for just this one `Binding`.

Comment: Ok but what my overall goal is to have my usercontrol react (get the whole Farmer object) when it's FarmerID property is changed on the parent control.  So I want to have the usercontrol use a ViewModel so that I can update the properties and have the View update. It just seems like the binding is over complicated to me.  I'd think there has to be an easier way to bind to a viewmodel and also have a dependency property on the control.

Comment: Guess I can't answer my own question, but here's what i was going to put in for an answer:

The control was actually looking to the parent view model for the data that I'm binding to.  Once I figured that out, everything started to bind correctly.  Thank you everyone for you help.

Comment: Oh... that's just what I was going to say.